# agetty / tty / telnet settings help

Tags: command-line, tty, telnet

I am trying to set up a ubuntu 20.04 LTS install that allows telnet connections at 300bps - basically some very old hardware is connecting from across the web - assume Bell103 (pre-hayes) (this connection is happening online, not via a serial connection!)

When I connect to services that support 300bps (a BBS or MUD for example), everything is working, but when I connect to the server it gets as far as CONNECT, I can see the telnetd initiating and running - but nothing happens. I get this response from any "modern" system.

My assumption is that the connection is truly made, but the settings and parameters are not configured sufficiently to allow communications to proceed.

My understanding is that inetd and agetty is responsible for this but I don't know enough about agetty or inetd to make this possible.

Maybe someone out there with a little more experience can help me adjust the config so that incoming telnet sessions can support a very bare bones stripped down low speed connection.

edit: should I be using mgetty instead??

Comment: Are you sure you're using Ubuntu Core 20 server? as it's a different system to the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server.  Ubuntu uses the *year* format for different products to the normal and more powerful *year.month* systems (the *year* products are *snap* only so have fewer options; but they do have benefits too so you may have reason for your choice).

Comment: Sorry, I'm using the word "server" too liberally. Yes, it's Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: Please correct your question, Ubuntu has had products that use *year* only since 2016 and they are all server products intended for *headless* operation.  Your question implies one of those *specialist* releases usually used in appliances, devices or cloud.